Drawing over a RichTextBox from a UserControl
I have a UserControl containing a RichTextLabel/RichTextBox. I'm using the Paint event from the UserControl to provide Debug/Design time information. This works well for normal Label instances as they support transparent background color so the information i draw directly onto the panel "shines" through - not optimal - but i dont have another idea to provide the information.
But with the RichTextBox/RichTextLabel this approach does not work as this control does not support transparency.
Is it possible to draw over other controls from the parent control?
Only other possibility i see is to place another label on top of all other controls, use that for the design time information and hide the label at runtime...

If a Control exposes a public Paint event, you can usually paint onto its surface. Not sure that's what you actually need, because provide Debug/Design time information is a very vague definition of this procedure. You could probably use an overlay instead - sort of an extended Tooltip (assuming a customized Tooltip is not what you're looking for) - so you just need one Device Context and the coordinates of the Control affected to, well, do whatever you're doing

@Jimi With design time information i mean that the controls have some required properties and if they are not set i want to draw a string that they are missing in the top left corner while in visual studio designer. If the properties are set i want to draw a string that has been generated from those required properties. the controls also have a special property that invert their behavior, if that property is set i want to add something like 'inverted' to the previous string # Not sure if the public paint event from my RichTextLabel gets me further, but i'll have a look into it
